# Variations: Can the source site also be the the root site?

Tags: variations

We are planning our variation hierarchy for a multi-lingual site.  We would like the root (e.g. www.conoso.com) to also be the source site for variations.

Is this possible?

If so, how do you create it through central admin?  The only place you can specify that the site is the source site is when you create a label, which creates a subsite with that label.

The goal is that most users *not* see url www.contoso.com/en-us when they're browsing the default source site in english.  It is ok for other countries to see /de-DE in the url if they're from Germany.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible since it would introduce overlap between labels / the navigation hierarchy.